# How to append single row to a cassandra table using pyspark?

Tags: python, cassandra, pyspark

I want to insert a new row into a Cassandra table which is already exists. I'm using pyspark_cassandra.

**spark version - 1.4.1**

**scala version - 2.10.6**

**cassandra version - 2.2.3**

**python version - 2.7.6**

**Python Script -**

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark_cassandra import CassandraSparkContext,Row
import pyspark_cassandra

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PySpark Cassandra Test").setMaster("spark://0.0.0.0:7077").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","http://127.0.0.1")

sc = CassandraSparkContext(conf=conf)
rdd = sc.parallelize([{
    "id": 101,
    "name": "ketan",
    }
])

rdd.saveToCassandra("users","temp")
```

Command to run above script -

```
sudo /usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --jars /path/to/pyspark-cassandra-assembly-<version>.jar \
--driver-class-path /path/to/pyspark-cassandra-assembly-<version>.jar \
--py-files /path/to/pyspark-cassandra-assembly-<version>.jar \
--conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=your,cassandra,node,names \
--master spark://spark-master:7077 \
yourscript.py
```

I got stuck because of below error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/yourscript.py", line 13, in <module>
    rdd.saveToCassandra("users","temp")
  File "/usr/local/spark/pyspark-cassandra-master/target/scala-2.10/pyspark-cassandra-assembly-0.3.5.jar/pyspark_cassandra/rdd.py", line 83, in saveToCassandra
  File "/usr/local/spark/pyspark-cassandra-master/target/scala-2.10/pyspark-cassandra-assembly-0.3.5.jar/pyspark_cassandra/util.py", line 93, in helper
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.newInstance.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.<init>(TypeConverter.scala:116)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.<clinit>(TypeConverter.scala)
    at pyspark_cassandra.PythonHelper.<init>(PythonHelper.scala:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.195.119:4040
17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3d6cd846-4e37-47d4-b1e0-d9e68a7d34b3/pyspark-c2b7061a-44f2-4e1c-bf90-ea30b81c3c7d
17/04/06 15:15:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3d6cd846-4e37-47d4-b1e0-d9e68a7d34b3
```

I tried to execute above code on pyspark shell and it is working fine for me. Data get inserted into a Cassandra table but while doing in python script I stuck at this point.

Am I missing some more configuration or else?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Scala Version mismatch error. Some components are using Scala 2.10 and others are using 2.11.

See the Spark Cassandra Connector [Faq](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#non-exclusive-list-of-scala-version-mismatch-errors) for more details.

The solution is to make sure all of your libraries are using the same version of Scala.

Comment: what I need to do to make all libraries are using same version of scala? I'm new to this approaches so please explain.

Comment: What this line means - To fix this make sure that the name has the correct Scala version suffix to match your Scala version. where I need to mention correct Scala version suffix?

Comment: Scala libs are usually marked with a "_s2.xx" suffix. This suffix is the Scala Version they were compiled against. The suffix must match for all libraries and the scala runtime in use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with following command

```
spark-submit --packages anguenot/pyspark-cassandra:2.4.0 yourscript.py
```